# XML HTTP request Jodel

Tags: javascript, json, http, client

I have spent alot of hours trying to solve this on my own and can't find the solution.

This is a function inside my jodelclient object.

```
this.sendPost = function(JodelPost)
{
    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest(); //create new httpRequest
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function (data) //This is the function that gets called when you recieve the server response
    {
        console.log(data); //Prints out the server response
    }

    var url = 'https://api.go-tellm.com/api/v2/posts/?'; //BaseUrl for jodel api

    httpRequest.open('POST', url+JSON.stringify(JodelPost));
    httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.token); //For a valid authirazation
    httpRequest.send(); //send it flying! 
};
```

The response from the server is

> "POST https://api.go-tellm.com/api/v2/posts/? 400 (Bad Request)"

and

> "Missing required property: location"

this is an example of the result of stringifying the JodelPost variable.

```
{
    "color": "FFBA00",
    "location": {
         "city": "Uppsala",
         "country": "46",
         "loc_accuracy": 0,
         "loc_coordinates": {
               "lat": "68.805532",
               "lng": "2.943903"
          },
         "name": "Uppsala"
    },
    "message": "HelloWorld"
}
```

When I was trying to solve this for myself I found this github repository doing the same thing but in python. It might be some useful information in there.

[Pydel](https://github.com/rolsdorph/pydel/blob/master/pydel/__init__.py)

Thanks in advance! I am quite new to this so simple explanations are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like the request isn't being created correctly. You're trying to send the data with the URL, but it should be passed in the XHR object's `send` function.

Also, the `onreadystatechange` function gets called each time the state changes, but you most likely want to check for the data when the state reaches `4` and the status is `200`. For more reading, see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp).

You'll also want to set the content-type header for your request.

Try something like this:

```
this.sendPost = function(JodelPost)
{
    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest(); //create new httpRequest
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) 
        {
            console.log(httpRequest.responseText);
        }
    }

    var url = 'https://api.go-tellm.com/api/v2/posts/?'; //BaseUrl for jodel api

    httpRequest.open('POST', url);
    httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.token);
    httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    httpRequest.send(JSON.stringify(JodelPost));
};
```